# select other collaborator in same task

Tags: mysql, sql

i tried alot with this statement but i can not get the result i want

this is collaboration table:

[image]

each collaborator should know other collaborator who have collaborator_complete =1, in the same task with him. also Joint_State = 'Accept'

for example:

for collabortor_ID=14
should know that 1,2,11 and 12 who have collaborator_complete =1 and share task 48 with 14.

i try this statement

[image]

it will select collaborators from task where 14 is not in this task
like the first two row of result in image2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    t2.Collaborator_ID
FROM collaborative_task t1
INNER JOIN collaborative_task t2
    ON t2.task_ID = t1.task_id    
    AND t2.collaborator_ID <> t1.collaborator_ID
WHERE
    t1.collaborator_id = 14
    AND t2.collaborator_complete = 1
    AND t2.Join_State = 'Accept'
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bd3e/5/0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at *other* rows.  That suggests a `join` or `in` or `exists`:

```
select ct.*
from collaborative_task ct
where collaborator_complete = 1 and join_state = 'Accept' and
      collaborator_id <> 14 and
      exists (select 1
              from collaborative_task ct2
              where ct2.task_id = ct.task_id and
                    ct2.collaborator_id = 14
             );
```